# "Since my father joined" vs "Since my father has joined"

Tags: grammar

> Since my father **has** joined this post, he has not taken bribe.

In the book I am reading, it says the correct one is:

> Since my father joined this post, he has not taken bribe.

How is the original statement incorrect? Or is it correct?

Comment: Neither one is correct, and unless you've made a typo or mis-transcribed the "correct" version, I'd suggest you throw that book away. For more details and any other follow-up questions (for example "Why are both wrong?" or "What is the correct way of phrasing it?"), please ask on our sister site dedicated to helping people learn English as a foreign language, [ELL.se]. This site, EL&U, is dedicated to the more arcane and academic issues of English.

Comment: Can you please explain why both the statements are wrong? 
I just can not find anything wrong with both of them.

Comment: As I said, if you want to know why both are wrong, please ask on our sister site, ELL.  The short story is your final noun doesn't agree in number with its antecedent.

Comment: @DanBron Eh? There seems to be an article missing -- "... has not taken a bribe" -- but what plural "antecedent" does *bribe* take? What "antecedent" is any noun required to take?

Comment: @StoneyB You could say "has not taken *a* bribe", but could equally say "has not taken bribe*s*", without introducing a new word. But I was being intentionally indirect with my advice, because I'm trying to coach ELL users to ask questions over at ELL, where they'll get better and better-targeted (to their demographic) answers. But of course your expert and well-presented answers are always welcome here, not least because I learn something from each of them!

Comment: @DanBron One of the most interesting things about both these sites is the different errors which different respondents discern in ill-formed texts. It's often very difficult for me to get past my presuppositions and recognize just what misunderstanding has created the error.

Comment: One could also interpret *since* to mean *because*:  *Because my father joined this post, he hasn’t taken any bribes (because otherwise he would have.)

Answer (score 1):

*Since* usually takes a specific point in the past as its object. The present perfect of a dynamic verb like *take*, a verb expressing an event or change of state, does not express a past event but a present state arising out of the past event, so it is not ordinarily suitable for defining the object of *since*. You should, as your book tells you, say

> Since my father took this post . . .

However, *since* may be employed with the present perfect of stative verbs such as *be* or *know* and stative constructions such as the progressive:

> Since I have known him he has impressed me.
>   Since I have been running daily I have lost weight.

In these cases, the perfect verb construction is in effect recategorized as an event: the *beginning* of the state.